# React native Navigation pass Database variable to all Screens

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator, watermelondb

I'm using "WatermelonDb" with "React-Navigation 5" to have a global access to the database variable from all my application screens.

From what i understand to pass initial variables to a screen in Navigation we use "initialParams".

However when i do so , i get an error :

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Database'
    |     property 'collections' -> object with constructor 'CollectionMap'
    |     property 'map' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'alarms' -> object with constructor 'Collection'
    --- property 'database' closes the circle
```

Is there an alternative for getting access to the database variable globally ?

Here is the part of my code where i try to pass database variable to intialParams

```
render()
  {
return ( 

  <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator 
              initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="HomeScreen"
          component={HomeScreen}      
         initialParams={{db:database} } // <-
          options={{title: 'Welcome',headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="AlarmDetails" options={{title: 'Welcome',headerShown: false}} component={AlarmDetails} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>

  )
```

Comment: What is a database here?

Comment: It's a watermelon database variable @AshwinMothilal

Comment: As the initialParams are shallow merged with params you pass, you need a JSON object at that place or you need to use HOC or Context like below answers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like passing not serializable objects into `initialParams` is not a way to go.

It is possible to implement it differently. You can just create some file, e.g. `database.js` which exports the database object and then import it inside your screens. To avoid repetition you also can, for example, create some [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), e.g `withDatabase` and then wrap your screens into this component.

```
withDatabase(AlarmDetails)
```

You can also use React Context for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Context
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it work by using React Context Api. You can check the example here https://www.naroju.com/how-to-use-react-context-to-pass-database-reference-to-child-components/. You can use the exact code for your use case.